# Different format mask in objective-c and swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, string-formatting

I have a program that have two libraries. One is in Objective-C and one is in Swift.

From my webserver I get format mask and set the format mask in first and second library.

I first library `NSNumberFormatter` is used so expected format mask is :

```
 #.#0 mm
```

But in second, that was updated to swift, they use now String.init(format:), so expected format is:

```
%1.2f mm
```

Why swift use different format mask and how to convert one to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert one to the other. You should probably raise an issue with the authors of the library because it's a breaking change.

`NSNumberFormatter` uses a completely different set of rules than `String(format:)`. Also, `NumberFormatter` is localized. The decimal point `.` is a pattern to choose either `.` or `,` depending on user locale. The `.` in `String(format:)` is a literal `.`.

Nothing to do with Swift or Obj-C. Both APIs are available in both languages.

Comment: So you can't convert them?

Comment: @MarkoZadravec No, you cannot convert them. The APIs are different, meant for different usages.